# How to perform a circular left shift in LC3

Tags: algorithm, bit-shift, lc3

We have been given an assignment for our Computer Systems Fundamentals class. The goal of the program is to display an unsigned integer value in three different ways: Binary, Decimal, and Hexadecimal. I have already completed the part for binary, and the decimal method will simply require division by 10 and printing the results. However, for hexadecimal the professor wants us to implement it using a circular left shift (in order to perform a left rotation).

IE.

```
  0010 1111 0000 1001
+ 0010 1111 0000 1001
  --------------------
  0101 1110 0001 0010
```

We have to do this 4x and then apply a mask to clear all bits from [15:4] in order to print out the ascii value of bits [3:0].

Here is my algorithm to solve this program.

```
;Loop 4 times -->initialization of for loop
;Begin For Loop
;Perform the left shift
;If the value after the left shift is performed has a carry of 1
;then add 1 to this value (the rotation)
;Otherwise if the value after the left shift is performed has a carry of 0
;Continue the value is already rotated
;Get the value of the number after the loop has completed
;Create a new loop that will go through the Digits
;Load R0 with the value of the digit that we land on
;Print that value to the screen
```

The problem that I am running into is the fact that I do not know how to find the carry bit of the number being shifted though.

For example:`0000 0000 0001 1011  ----> bit[4] is the carry bit after the left shift`

I don't know how to keep track of that to perform the circular shift.
I tried a mask of

```
1000 0000 0000 0000
```

but I don't think it
keeps track of any carry bit that doesn't occur on bit[15].

Help would be greatly appreciated, the book doesn't provide an example, and I can't find any sources online, I know that answering homework questions is generally frowned upon, but I am at my wits end! Its the weekend so I cannot contact the professor, and the assignment is due soon (not last minute, I have been stuck on this since Friday -_- ).

Thank you!

EDIT: MORE INFORMATION

DIGITS is this: `DIGITS .STRINGZ "0123456789ABCDEF" ;Digit_String`
It will take the value of the of [3:0] after the 4 rotations and will determine which ascii character to print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never heard of **LC3** before so I do not know the instruction set but from quick google you have:

- `and,add,not` instructions
- `N,Z,P` flags
- `2'os` complement ALU

Which is really not much (it lacks the basic instructions) so you have to do everything backwards. However there are ways how to do **cyclic rotation** for example like this:

1. for rotation left of `r0` you can use `add r0,r0,r0`
2. to obtain carry you can use sign of value before rotation

   in 2'os complement if the **MSB** bit is set the value is **negative**. So you need to set flags with some neutral arithmetic operation and test `N,P` flags. For example `add r0,r0,#0`

   Another way is like you guessed `and` the **MSB** and test `Z` flag but I am not sure if you can store `1000 0000 0000 0000 bin` as positive number as I did not see any distinction between signed and unsigned constants I assume they are all signed and putting this value as positive will overflow compiler/interpreter making it most likely zero. try to use `#-32768` instead.

When put together let have the value in `r0` so:

```
LD  R0,#your value

; extract MSB bit to R1
LD  R1,#0    ; hope this is load
ADD R0,R0,#0 ; MSB -> N/P flags
BRp REL0     ; hope this is conditional jump if positive
LD  R1,#1    ; carry was set
REL0

; shift
ADD R0,R0,R0 ; shift left (arithmetic)
ADD R0,R0,R1 ; shift left (cyclic)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much doing the same assignment. I think I actually have your same class lol. I know people on this site look down on sharing code, but heres the section that youre having trouble with. Take a look at it and try to append yours appropriately. Also, I was having the same problem with the mask, try using xF000 as the mask to get the MSB(most sig byte).

```
ST R1, HEX1
ST R7, HEX7
AND R1, R1, 0
AND R7, R7, 0
AND R2, R2, 0
ADD R1, R0, #0
LD R4, HEXMASK
ADD R6, R6, #4; counter 2
    OUTERROT
LD R3, INMASK   
LD R5, OUTMASK
ST R5, HEXSAVE
LD R5, HEXMASK2 
AND R7, R1, R5; R7=MSB
LD R5, HEXSAVE
ADD R2, R2, #4
    SHIFT   
ADD R1, R1, R1
ADD R2, R2, #-1
BRz EXITSHF
BR  SHIFT
    EXITSHF
AND R0, R0, 0
ADD R0, R1, 0
AND R1, R1, 0
    SHFTR   
ST R4, HEXSAVE
AND R4, R4, 0
AND R4, R7, R3
BRz DONOTHING
NOT R1, R1
NOT R5, R5
AND R4, R1, R5
NOT R4, R4
NOT R1, R1
NOT R5, R5
ADD R1, R4, 0
BRz SHFTREX
    DONOTHING
LD R4, HEXSAVE
ADD R5, R5, R5
ADD R3, R3, R3
BRz SHFTREX
BR  SHFTR
    SHFTREX
ADD R0, R1, R0
AND R1, R1, 0
ADD R1, R0, 0
ST R0, HEXSAVE
ST R1, HEXSAVE1 
AND R0, R0, 0
AND R0, R1, R4
ST R3, CONV3
AND R3, R3, #0  
LEA R3, DIGITS 
    START
ADD R3, R3, 1 
ADD R0, R0, #-1 
    BRnp    START
LDR R0, R3, 0
LD R3, CONV3
TRAP x21
LD R0, HEXSAVE
ADD R6, R6, #-1
BRz HEXEXIT
BR  OUTERROT
    HEXEXIT     
LD R1, HEX1
LD R7, HEX7
RET
  ;Save Area        
 HEXMASK    .FILL   x000F
 HEXMASK2   .FILL   XF000
 INMASK .FILL   x1000
 OUTMASK    .FILL   x0001
 ASCII  .FILL   X0030
 HEX1   .BLKW   1
 HEX7   .BLKW   1
 HEXSAVE1   .BLKW   1
  HEXSAVE   .BLKW   1
 CONV3  .BLKW   1
```

Never specified earlier which mask. There are actually 4 masks to use 2 for right shifting the MSB, 1 for obtaining the MSB, and 1 for obtaining at the end the bits in B[3:0]. Try to recognize the difference.

Comment: if `xF000` is hex value then you are masking 4 bits not 1 and hard to say what value will be left in compiler/interpreter after overflow of this value to 2'os complement so may be just 3 bits ...